# using ASP.NET's EditorFor with an abstract type. finds correct template as collection type, but as a plain property tries to find base type template

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages

in my application i can list templates using the editorfor htmlhelper with a collection type with an abstract class as the generic parameter in the viewmodel, but i'd like more control over the template but i'm struggling to load the correct template using a loop, editorfor decides to use the basetype name when looking for an editor template when i loop through the collection

here's an overly simplified example:

/models/basetype.cs

```
public abstract class BaseType {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LabelText { get => nameof(this); }
}
```

/models/inheritedtype1.cs

```
public class InheritedType1 : BaseType {
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

/models/inheritedtype1.cs

```
public class InheritedType2 : BaseType {
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

/views/shared/editortemplates/InheritedType1.cshtml

```
@model InteritedType1
<label asp-for="@Model.LabelText"></label>
<input asp-for="@Model.Value" class="form-control" />
```

/views/shared/editortemplates/InheritedType2.cshtml

```
@model InteritedType2
<label asp-for="@Model.LabelText"></label>
<input asp-for="@Model.Value" class="form-control" />
```

/controllers/homecontroller.cs

```
public class controller : basecontroller {
    public readonly MyServiceType _service;
    public controller(MyServiceType service) => _service = service;
    public IActionResult Index(ICollection<BaseType> baseTypes) {
        var vm = new vm() { 
            BaseTypeCollection = _service.getBaseTypes() // impltementation is unimportant, collection includes both InheritedType1 and InheritedType2 types
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

/models/vm.cs

```
public class vm {
    public IEnumerable<BaseType> BaseTypeCollection { get;set; }
}
```

/views/home/index.cshtml

```
@model vm
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.BaseTypeCollection)
```

above works, it loads the templates for types inheriting base type

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.BaseTypeCollection.ToArray()[0])
```

above tries to find base type template

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.BaseTypeCollection.ToArray()[0], "InheritedType2") // works but is pointless
```

above works, but i have to manually enter the template name as a parameter

```
@var a = Model.BaseTypeCollection.ToArray();
for(int i = 0; i < a.Count(); i++){
    Html.EditorFor(x => a[i], a[i].GetType().Name, $"SearchCriteria[{i}]")
}
```

and above also works but to be honest if i'm doing this much i might as well write out the html manually.

i just don't understand why i can't pass a single property that inherits BaseType to editorfor and have it use the correct template instead of looking for the BaseType editor template

Comment: Confusing which `EditorFor` calls shown are working and which ones are not, also clarify your expectations.  Clarify your expected working example.

Comment: `@editorfor(x => x.BaseTypeCollection)` works, it lists the correct types that inherit BaseType with my custom editor templates.

`@editorfor(x => x.BaseTypeCollection.ToArray()[0], "InheritedType2")` works but i have to manually pass the template i want as a parameter

`@editorfor(x => x.BaseTypeCollection.ToArray()[0])` tries to load an editor template for `BaseType` instead of the type inheriting `BaseType` e.g. `InheritedType1` and `InheritedType2`